# SSRS/RDLC Detail Data Single Value repeated

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc

I have been plagued with an issue for SSRS (really RDLC report viewer report) in that the details rendered in a report are the same value all the way down in a group. I faced this before and ended up having to create a new view and pull it into the solution and rebuild the report from scratch. As I am having this again I really want to know what else to try. I have deleted the tableadpator and added it back again, tried cleaning and rebuilding solution. I had altered a view, added a couple of columns to the end, so that is my suspect item as another report that uses the same base view now has a similar problem. This is not a code specific example and sure hoping someone else has seen this behavior and know how to get rid of it.

So I have a ASP.Net web application that uses the report viewer to render some reports, RDLC. I use entity framework for my data access and bind the data to the report.

Comment: Make sure you're not only displaying the `First` value or `SUM`.Double check the TextFields.

Comment: That was not the issue. I will post what I found for someone else to hopefully learn from.

Answer (score 0):

I found what seems to have been the problem. I am using Entity Framework (EF) and I updated some views to add additional columns for reporting. EF randomly picks a key for columns. If I manually set the key to what it should be, and I set my grouping to be on an ID column rather than text (not sure this really fixed it, but adding as it is part of my solution), then the report is now not duplicating the same data for each row. The odd thing was the count of rows for the group was correct, just somehow would only render the first row data for each row. I know this is not a great example of the root problem and fix, but at least all the reports I had issues with are now working and the only thing that changed for some was the EF model was updated for the view that would bind to the RDLC report.